# Script that schedules a file execution

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python script that with either apscheduler or crontab that can schedule another python file to run at specific intervals without having the command prompt open all the time. Here is some code i wrote to try create a text file every minute. But it's not working. My main goal again is to run a file not a function but I just started with a function for now.

```
def my_cron_job1():
    print "cron job 1"
    target = open('results.txt', 'w')
    target.write("HELLLO")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
    sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone='MST')

    sched.add_job(my_cron_job1, 'cron', id='my_cron_job1', minute=1)
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you only make one 'results.txt' file, it is because you are always making the same 'results.txt' file.

I would recommend using string formatting to create numbered 'result' files. This way you are always creating a new file.

Another possible issue is that "minute" should be "minutes" as per the apscheduer documentation (http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/interval.html)